# ¿Cómo ejecutar un .exe desde php?

Tags: php, php7

Para ponerlos en contexto:

Quiero automatizar el cambio de componentes en delphi, para ello uso **convert.exe** (un ejecutable de líneas de comandos que convierte los .DFM en ficheros de texto), luego **refind.exe** (un ejecutable de líneas de comando basado en expresiones regulares que reemplaza los componentes de forma masiva), todo esto que se haga automáticamente, simplemente indicando el path del proyecto y los nombres de los componentes que se desean sustituir.

Como debería funcionar:

1. Un script PHP que copie el fichero "convert.exe" a la ruta del proyecto y lo ejecute en el cmd.
2. Luego que copie "refind.exe" a la ruta del proyecto y ejecute en el cmd (y las expresiones regulares las generaré en base a ciertas variables, pero esto no tiene importancia.

Problema:
He tenido problemas al intentar codificar el punto 1. He intentado ejecutar **shell_exec** y **exec** y ninguno me ha funcionado, me da la sensación que no puedo acceder correctamente a la ruta del proyecto, como si el comando se está ejecutando en otro directorio y, por ende, no se encuentran los .DFM.
Hice un **echo** del comando que genera mi script y si copio este comando y lo ejecuto manualmente en el CMD, funciona a la perfección, pero si intento que lo haga el script me dice que no ha encontrando ningún fichero .DFM.

```
Comando generado: "C:\Users\user\Desktop\Chequeando convert\miProyecto\codigo\convert.exe" -t -i *.dfm
```

Ya que, lo anterior no funcionó, intenté con 3 comandos (o sea, ejecuté 3 veces shell_exec / exec)

1. cd "C:\Users\user\Desktop\Chequeando convert\miProyecto\codigo"
2. dir
3. convert.exe -t -i *.dfm

Pero el resultado es el mismo: `Delphi Form Conversion Utility Version 5.0 Copyright (c) 1995,99 Inprise Corporation No files found matching *.dfm`

¿Cómo puedo hacer?

Comment: ¿Podrías [edit] tu pregunta y agregar el código PHP que intentaste? ¿Intentaste mover el `.exe` a la raiz del disco, fuera de un directorio protegido?

Comment: Revisa [`getcwd()`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.getcwd.php) y [`chdir()`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.chdir.php).

Comment: @Sal probablemente esa sea una solución, pero me decanté por hacerlo de otra forma. El script PHP será el encargado de la creación y ejecución de un fichero .BAT (y éste será el encargado de mover los EXE y ejecutarlos).